# How to disable `npm-merge-drive` in git merge

Tags: git, npm, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

When I cherry-pick some commit that has conflicts with `package-lock.json` file, the `npm-merge-drive` run

when it failed the cherry-pick fails, how can I remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the following command:

```bash
git config --global --remove-section merge.npm-merge-driver
```

this will remove it...